# IPsec connection established but xl2tpd times out

Tags: networking, ipsec, openswan, xl2tpd

This may or may not be related to [my problem with passing `ipsec verify`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337036/openswans-ipsec-verify-fails-on-two-or-more-interfaces-found-checking-ip-forw).

I have configured L2TP/IPsec VPN on Ubuntu 13.04 [following Ubuntu's community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/L2TPServer) and while IPsec connection seems to be established correctly, connection to xl2tpd fails. Here's a log from the client

```
Aug 25 14:07:10.058 004 "connection-name" #2: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established transport mode {ESP=>0x542d1443 <0x2e94cf9a xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=none}
Aug 25 14:07:11.060 xl2tpd[31068]: Connecting to host my.server's.ip, port 1701
Aug 25 14:07:16.065 xl2tpd[31068]: Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel 6146.  Closing.
```

Syslog on the server shows nothing at all. Even with

```
debug network 
debug tunnel
```

in the configuration. It's as if the connection to xl2tpd is never made.

What's going on? Could it be a firewall issue? I have tried flushing all my rules and more permissive configurations to no avail. Or is it some problem with forwarding [as indicated by ipsec verify](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337036/openswans-ipsec-verify-fails-on-two-or-more-interfaces-found-checking-ip-forw)?

Or at least, how can I get more information?